# Change backgroundColor of sectiontitle in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.5

I have a `UITableView` with sections and the title for them I m setting in `titleForHeaderInSection` like this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [NSString stringwithFormat :@"Section %d",section];
}
```

Defaulty it comes with graycoloured background with textcolor white.How can I change it to some other colour.?

Gone through google and found to set in `viewForHeaderinSection`.
But I did't use it to setheaders .So I dont want to write in it.

How can I write it in `titleForHeaderInSection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titleForHeaderInSection` : This delegate of `UITableView` is used to set only text. You can see below it's return type it `NSString`.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different
}
```

In order to achieve the customized view for a section header your only option is `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method. I can assure there's no way you can set the view for header using `titleForHeaderInSection` Also, `viewForHeaderInSection` acts exactly same as `titleForHeaderInSection` You can see implement it as below :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Customized your view however you want.

    return myCustomizedView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 6 and later

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section 
    {
       UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,          tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
       if (section == integerRepresentingYourSectionOfInterest)
             [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
       else 
             [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
      return headerView;
    }
```

Comment: nice answer but can't display header title :(

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,25)]autorelease];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,25)];
    tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    NSString * headerText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",section];
    tempLabel.text= headerText;
    [tempView addSubview: tempLabel];
    [tempLabel release];
    return tempView;
}
```

**And**

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 25;
}
```